# Solving the Ordinary Differential Equation $\frac{dy}{dx} = c_{1} + c_{2}y + \frac{c_{3}}{y} , y(0) = c , c >0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was trying to solve this ODE $\frac{dy}{dx} = c_{1} + c_{2}y + \frac{c_{3}}{y} , y(0) = c , c >0$.

where $c_{1},c_{2},c_{3}$ are three real numbers say $c_{1} < 0,c_{2},c_{3} > 0$.

I thought of using separation of variables giving me $x = \int(\frac{y}{c_{1}y+c_{2}y^2+c_{3}})dy + c$.

Next I am trying to reduce the denominator into a perfect square thng like of the form $(a + by)^2 + c$ ,so equating $(a + by)^2 = c_{1}y + c_{2}y^2 + c_{3}$ 
we get,

$(c_{1}y + c_{2}y^2 + c_{3}) = (\sqrt{\frac{-c_{1}^2}{4.c_{2}}} + \sqrt{c_{2}}.y)^2 + (c_{3} - \frac{c_{1}^2}{4.c_{2}})$

thus $x = \int(\frac{y}{(\sqrt{\frac{-c_{1}^2}{4.c_{2}}} + \sqrt{c_{2}}.y)^2 + (c_{3} - \frac{c_{1}^2}{4.c_{2}})}) dy + c$.

Now I am stuck at this point.
Also it makes me think whether there exists an analytic solution to this ODE?

Comment: Well, at least Wolfram says that the closed form of the integral exists. However, I do not think that the inverse function of this integral does.

Comment: Hint: write the numerator as $y+c-c$ with a suitable constant so that $y+c$ is the derivative of the denominator (up to a factor). Then remains to integrate the inverse of a quadratic polynomial. By completing the square you get rid of the linear term and end-up with the derivative of $\arctan$ or $\text{artanh}$.

Comment: I agree but I am curious why Matlab returned $$\mathrm{log}\!\left(x - \left(\frac{1}{2\, b} - \frac{a\, \sqrt{a^2 - 4\, b\, c}}{2\, \left(a^2\, b - 4\, b^2\, c\right)}\right)\, \left(a + 2\, b\, x\right)\right)\, \left(\frac{1}{2\, b} - \frac{a\, \sqrt{a^2 - 4\, b\, c}}{2\, \left(a^2\, b - 4\, b^2\, c\right)}\right) + \mathrm{log}\!\left(x - \left(\frac{1}{2\, b} + \frac{a\, \sqrt{a^2 - 4\, b\, c}}{2\, \left(a^2\, b - 4\, b^2\, c\right)}\right)\, \left(a + 2\, b\, x\right)\right)\, \left(\frac{1}{2\, b} + \frac{a\, \sqrt{a^2 - 4\, b\, c}}{2\, \left(a^2\, b - 4\, b^2\, c\right)}\right)
$$ @Yve

Comment: @YvesDaoust It would be great if you can help me with the answer provided by me below?

Comment: What Matlab returned can indeed be seen as the sum of a logarithm and an $\text{artanh}$.

Comment: Yes as $artanhx ≡ ln[(1 + x) /(1 − x)] /2$ but any explanation of how two different integrals ?@YvesDaoust

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By a linear transform $y=ax+b$, you can establish

$$\frac y{c_1y+c_2y^2+c_3}=\frac{ax+b}{c(x^2\pm1)}$$ where the sign is dictated by an expression below.

For this, write

$$c_1(ax+b)+c_2(a^2x^2+2abx+b^2)+c_3$$ and identify

$$\begin{cases}c_2a^2=c,\\c_1a+2c_2ab=0,\\c_1b+c_2b^2+c_3=\pm c.\end{cases}$$ (You draw $b$ from the second equation, then $c$ from the third and $a$ from the first. $c$ must have the sign of $c_2$.)

Now,

$$\int\frac x{x^2\pm1}dx=\ln(x^2\pm1)$$ and

$$\int\frac1{x^2\pm1}=\arctan x\text{ or }\text{artanh }x.$$

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing that, why don't you just multiply the whole expression by $y$ and the let $y^2=t$.

Comment: sorry but then what next?

Comment: But how would the term $c_1 y$ behave?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I agree what Yves say that I must get some type $\log$ and derivative of $\arctan$ function , but I am curious that when I consider the above integral which i want to find $\int(\frac{y}{c_{1}y+c_{2}y^2+c_{3}})dy $ then MATLAB returns

where for simplification I have taken $c_{1} = a ,c_{2} = b , c_{3} = c$

$\mathrm{log}\!\left(y - \left(\frac{1}{2\, b} - \frac{a\, \sqrt{a^2 - 4\, b\, c}}{2\, \left(a^2\, b - 4\, b^2\, c\right)}\right)\, \left(a + 2\, b\, y\right)\right)\, \left(\frac{1}{2\, b} - \frac{a\, \sqrt{a^2 - 4\, b\, c}}{2\, \left(a^2\, b - 4\, b^2\, c\right)}\right) + \mathrm{log}\!\left(y - \left(\frac{1}{2\, b} + \frac{a\, \sqrt{a^2 - 4\, b\, c}}{2\, \left(a^2\, b - 4\, b^2\, c\right)}\right)\, \left(a + 2\, b\, y\right)\right)\, \left(\frac{1}{2\, b} + \frac{a\, \sqrt{a^2 - 4\, b\, c}}{2\, \left(a^2\, b - 4\, b^2\, c\right)}\right)$

and when I do proper calculations in order to reduce the integrand into a suitable form to solve it analytically then i get a reduced form of integrand like this -

$\int(\frac{y}{(\sqrt{\frac{-c_{1}^2}{4.c_{2}}} + \sqrt{c_{2}}.y)^2 + (c_{3} - \frac{c_{1}^2}{4.c_{2}})}) dy$

then MATLAB returns me

$\frac{\mathrm{log}\!\left(\frac{y}{b} - \frac{\left(2\, \sqrt{b}\, y + \sqrt{- a^2\, b}\right)\, \left(2\, b\, c - \frac{a^2\, b^2}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{b}\, \sqrt{a^2\, b^2 - 4\, b\, c}\, \sqrt{- a^2\, b}}{2}\right)}{b^{\frac{5}{2}}\, \left(4\, c - a^2\, b\right)}\right)\, \left(2\, b\, c - \frac{a^2\, b^2}{2} + \sqrt{2}\, \sqrt{b}\, \sqrt{\frac{a^2\, b^2}{2} - 2\, b\, c}\, \sqrt{-\frac{a^2\, b}{4}}\right)}{4\, b^2\, c - a^2\, b^3} - \frac{\mathrm{log}\!\left(\frac{y}{b} + \frac{\left(2\, \sqrt{b}\, y + \sqrt{- a^2\, b}\right)\, \left(\frac{a^2\, b^2}{2} - 2\, b\, c + \frac{\sqrt{b}\, \sqrt{a^2\, b^2 - 4\, b\, c}\, \sqrt{- a^2\, b}}{2}\right)}{b^{\frac{5}{2}}\, \left(4\, c - a^2\, b\right)}\right)\, \left(\frac{a^2\, b^2}{2} - 2\, b\, c + \sqrt{2}\, \sqrt{b}\, \sqrt{\frac{a^2\, b^2}{2} - 2\, b\, c}\, \sqrt{-\frac{a^2\, b}{4}}\right)}{4\, b^2\, c - a^2\, b^3}
$

(*)where for simplification I have taken $c_{1} = a ,c_{2} = b , c_{3} = c$

Even thought the above two solutions are of the form $\log() + \log()$ but still then are the two expressions or solutions the same (as it must be as they are derived from the same integration I guess if  I have done it right.)